Bug in PDP-11/23 Plus diagnostic JKDIB0?
Diagnostic JKDIB0 is one of the PDP-11/23B (aka as PDP-11/23 Plus) diagnostics that tests the behaviour of the BDV11 line time clock (LTC). It specifically contains the following code from address 011064:
3$:  CLR @LKS         ; DISABLE RTC INTERRUPTS
     CLR R0
     MOV #XXX,@RTCVT  ; SET RTC INTERRUPT VECTOR FOR ERROR
     JSR PC,WRPPSW    ; CHANGE PSW TO PRIORITY 5
     .WORD 240
     ERROR 146
XXX: 
     Test continues at this point

This code disables the LTC interrupt but to continue the test expects an interrupt to occur and the remainder of the test to be executed from label XXX. If no interrupt occurs - which I would expect - the code reaches the ERROR 146 (which is an EMT 104146) and generates a "RTC INTERRUPT DID NOT OCCUR" error.
This code seems incorrect to me, especially as the JKDJB0 PDP-11/23B diagnostics in TEST 626 verifies exactly the opposite behaviour. The only difference I see between these diagnostics is some timing behaviour. In TEST 626 after the LTC interrupt is disabled a wait loop of 30 milliseconds is executed before the priority is lowered and an interrupt could occur.
Does anyone understand the interrupt behaviour of the BDV11 line time clock? Can an interrupt be generated even if the LTC interrupts are disabled?

Pure guess, unencumbered by knowledge: If the clock has already requested an interrupt, then subsequently disabling interrupts may not rescind that request. So as soon as the process priority drops low enough, the interrupt proceeds.

Another non-answer, but this paper by Supnik says that -11 interrupt implementation was all over the place.

@dave Your comments make me realize that the matter may be more complex than I thought. While hoping for a definitive answer I'll try to investigate it further.

The notion that disabling interrupts not necessarily implies that pending interrupts are cleared immediately and all sorts of behaviour variants exist opens up new possibilties in my understanding of the matter. With this insight I studied JKDJB0 test 626 again. The test sets the priority level at 7, disables the LTC interrupts, waits 30 milliseconds, lowers the priority level and then expects no interrupt to occur. This probably impllies that on disabling LTC interrupts a pending interrupt isn't cleared immediately but at the next clock tick.

You should answer your own question!

Reverse engineering JKDJB0 test 626 with the enhanced insight from the comments leads me to the conclusion that disabling LTC interrupts doesn't clear a possibly pending interrupt immediately but that interrupts are cleared at the next clock tick. That test sets the priority level at 7, disables the LTC interrupts, waits 30 milliseconds (i.e. at least a clock tick period), lowers the priority level and then expects no interrupt to occur.
